# Mutiple div without any unique id

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng

I am automating in selenium and I have multiple div without unique id. So for the xpath that I am searching, I am getting 3 records, where I want to get each record separately.
Is there a way that I can get the desired div one by one?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

two ways to deal with this situation :

1. `xpath indexing`
2. `find_elements`

**Xpath indexing :**

```
//div[@class='OSInline']//i[@class='icon fa fa-pencil-square fa-3x']
```

to apply indexing on this :

wrap it up with parenthesis

```
(//div[@class='OSInline']//i[@class='icon fa fa-pencil-square fa-3x'])[1]
```

or

```
(//div[@class='OSInline']//i[@class='icon fa fa-pencil-square fa-3x'])[2]
```

Now coming to `find_elements` :

```
for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='OSInline']//i[@class='icon fa fa-pencil-square fa-3x']"):
    element.click() # or do whatever you wanna do with element. (It is a single web element)
```

or

```
list_of_ele = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='OSInline']//i[@class='icon fa fa-pencil-square fa-3x']")
list_of_ele[0].click()
```

**or**

```
list_of_ele[1].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

use full xpath like below :

/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/h3/a

Comment: Is there a special reason why you undid the formatting improvement proposed by a well-meaning user?